# Close, Minimize and Maximize buttons on Electron

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm currently using electron 1.0, and i can't find a way to use the remote module with, every single tutorial i try, none of them works, i just give me an error "Cannot find module 'remote'".

Here is the snippet from my index.js (my external .js file which is called on my html file) where the function is located:

```
 (function () {

 var remote = require('remote');
 var BrowserWindow = remote.require('browser-window');

 function init() {
      document.getElementById("min-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
           var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
           window.minimize();
      });

      document.getElementById("max-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
           var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
           window.maximize();
      });

      document.getElementById("close-btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
           var window = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
           window.close();
      });
 };

 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (document.readyState == "complete") {
           init();
      }
 };

})();
```

and here is my main.js file:

```
 const electron = require('electron') 
 const app = electron.app
 const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

 let mainWindow

 function createWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, frame: false,          title:"Gestão Prefeitura", center: true})
   mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
   mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools()
   mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
   mainWindow = null
 })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

 app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
 if (process.platform !== 'darwin') { 
 app.quit()
 }
})

app.on('activate', function () {
if (mainWindow === null) {
         createWindow()
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you need to require built-in Electron modules has changed in Electron v1.0.0 and they are now all exposed through the `electron` module. Also the `remote` module now has properties that correspond to main-process modules. So, instead of:

```
var remote = require('remote');
var BrowserWindow = remote.require('browser-window');
```

you should write:

```
const { remote } = require('electron');
const { BrowserWindow } = remote;
```